# Getting AllJoyn to run on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, alljoyn

I've been trying to get AllJoyn to work on iOS for quite some time now. I've tried a couple of different tutorials (obviously including the official one), but always got stuck at various errors that I've lost track of.

I am asking here if somebody knows a tutorial that I can follow exactly step-by-step and get it to compile at least or if somebody has a working (self-contained, 64 Bit if possible) XCode project template. Any help is very much appreciated.